# How to write some italic words in first slidify slide?

Tags: rstudio, slidify

How can I write in italic font the words between ** ** for the first slide in slidify?

```
---
title       : Yield loss of target spot (**Corynespora casiicola**) in soybean
subtitle    : 
author      : 
job         : 
logo        : logo1.png
biglogo     : logo2.png
framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
widgets     : []            # {mathjax, bootstrap, quiz}
mode        : selfcontained
hitheme     : tomorrow      # {tomorrow, tomorrow_night, solarized_dark, solarized_light}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
```